# A identity on hafnians of Gram matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, symmetric-matrices, convex-geometry

The setting is as follows: we've got vectors $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ in $\mathrm{R}^n$, and each of them is some vector from the standard orthonormal basis $e_1,\ldots,e_n$. I need to show that if some $e_k$ appears an odd number of times among those vectors, then their corresponding Gramm matrix $(a_i,a_j)=<x_i,x_j>$ has a null hafnian.

I haven't found too many papers or articles about hafnians or their properties, so I'm having a tough times dealing with this. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=(a_{ij})=(\langle x_{i}, x_{j} \rangle)$ be the Gram matrix of the $x_{i}$'s. Since $A$ is symmetric and has entries in $\{0,1\}$, you can think of $A$ as the adjacency matrix of a graph on vertex set $V=\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ and edge set $E=\{\{i,j\}:x_{i}=x_{j}\}$ (i.e., vertices $i$ and $j$ are adjacent iff $x_{i}=x_{j}$). Call this graph $G_{A}.$ It's worth noting that because the diagonal of $A$ is all $1$'s, each vertex has a self-loop, but we can disregard these since the Hafnian never looks at the diagonal entries of $A.$

Now, suppose $k$ is odd and that $x_{i_{1}},x_{i_{2}},\dots,x_{i_{k}}$ are all copies of the standard basis vector $e_{i}.$  The Hafnian of $A$ counts perfect matchings of $G_{A}$, where self-loops are not allowed in a matching. The vertices $i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{k}$ are a clique of size $k$ in the graph, and none of the $i_{j}$'s have neighbors outside of this clique. Since $k$ is odd, there is no way to match the vertices in this clique, and thus $G_{A}$ has no perfect matchings.

You can also see this from the definition of the Hafnian, $\text{haf}(A)=\frac{1}{(n/2)!2^{(n/2)}}\sum_{\sigma \in S_{n}}\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{\sigma(i)\sigma(i+1)}$, with $S_{n}$ the set of permutations of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}.$ For any $\sigma \in S_{n}$, the product $\prod_{i=1}^{n-1}A_{\sigma(i)\sigma(i+1)}$ must be $0$ since $\sigma$ must map an $i_{j}$ to some element not in $\{i_{1},i_{2},\dots,i_{k}\}.$